# What are best practices for dealing with application errors caused by bots?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, bots

Every day I have bots hitting my application with random urls, which results in application errors. Because they try urls like `https://smashnotes.com/p/*/e/*/s/*` , I cannot entirely suppress this error from showing up again because if I do, it causes legitimate errors to go unseen. But I also don't want to rush to my phone every time there's a notification from Honebadger telling me there's an error, only to find out it's yet another fake hit.

I am thinking I should just write an exception loop that if parameters are missing, or they don't match any existing parameters, then redirect to the root. This way it won't exactly count as an error. There is a small chance that I will miss some legitimate errors too, like when the path urls are missing, or params were passed incorrectly. Maybe I can log those, and check them occasionally, but not have to be continuously alerted.

How would you solve these bot errors?

Comment: Check out https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/1.5/ using it you can validate incoming parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Yakov . Will definitely ensure validation. I guess that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific with what those params means? If `p`, `e`, `s` are actually params or just random stuff aswel?

Without much information about the state of your application I can only suggest you to use :constraints at your route definition allied with a regexp to ensure that params hitting are in an appropriate format.

[Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints)